# resampling data in 2 subset to eqully

Tags: discrete-mathematics, resampling

Could you help me a little bit

i have 2 subset binary image curve A and B ,How i resampling data A or B to Equally.

For Example

curve A,   {(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5)}

curve B,   {(5,5),(5,4),(5,3)}

i would like resampling the number of element B to 5 for equally A

B( resampling )==>  {(5,5),(5,4.5),(5,4),(5,3.5),(5,3)}

i done to implement this method in c++. 
but I do not sure that is call linear interplolation method
and another problem i do not know how to write this method equally A and B in term of Math formular or in term of geometry discrete?

thank you very much

kitti

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Lagrange interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).